# Mapkit How To Drop a Pin on a Specific Location?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mapkit

Let's say there's a subway near my house. I want to drop 1 pin on this EXACT subway. I would like to know how to drop a pin on a specific place like this particular subway for example. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add MKPointAnnotation:

```
MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
point.coordinate = coordinateOfSubway;
point.title = @"Sample title";
[_mapView addAnnotation:point];
```

Remember to implement MKMapView's delegate methods.

Comment: when i try to plug my coordinates in i get an error saying "Assigning CLLocationCoordinate2D from incompatible type double". Could you give an example of something that could take the place of coordinateOfSubway?

Comment: Here you have: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(doubleValue, doubleValue)